# Why was my question put on-hold by me?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, vote-to-close

[My question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193856/) was put on-hold recently with a banner:

> put on hold as off-topic by R S, Melebius, Pilot6, user68186, vidarlo - 9 mins ago

But R S is me and I don't remember I did that to myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [post's timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1193856/timeline#closure_1164586), it seems like you voted to close it around 11h ago (08:17 UTC) using the custom *Off-topic → Other* reason, which also let you add a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193856/can-i-convert-connection-type-using-router?noredirect=1#comment1999106_1193856):

> It seems it's more about hardware/software not related to Ubuntu.

[image]

Probably you wanted to just add the comment and accidentally picked the close option instead?

Anyway, it is reopened now.

Comment: Right, my memory. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you earn 250+ reputation points, you also earn "[view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)" privilege. Some time in the past you might have cast a close vote on your own question (may be unknowingly). That's why your display name is being displayed on the banner. You can confirm the close votes you have cast in [closure tab under votes](https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure).

**Update:** The question has now reopened. You are one the user who voted to reopen the question just like you were one of the close voters. For more information, see [timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1193856/timeline).

Comment: How could I remove it? My close vote.

Comment: @RS Once the question has been closed the banner can only be removed when the question reopens. I have cast a reopen vote. As of now there are 3 reopen votes. It would require 5 votes to get reopened. You can cast your vote too :)

Comment: I did already. Thank you.